# F# check if a string contains only number

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I am trying to figure out a nice way to check if a string contains only number. This is the result of my effort but it seems really verbose:

```
let isDigit c = Char.IsDigit c

let rec strContainsOnlyNumber (s:string)=
    let charList = List.ofSeq s
    match charList with
        | x :: xs -> 
            if isDigit x then
                strContainsOnlyNumber ( String.Concat (Array.ofList xs))
            else 
                false
        | [] -> true
```

for example it seems really ugly that I have to convert a string to char list and then back to a string.
Can you figure out a better solution?

Comment: Is this homework?  In any case, I'd use `Seq.forall`.

Comment: Wow, ok let's say it's for homework but actually I'm just switching from C#. Seq.forall (fun elem -> isDigit elem) "12345" this work as well and it's better

Comment: You can shorten that to `Seq.forall Char.IsDigit "12345"` without the need for an intermediate `isDigit` function

Comment: I think someone needs to write the answer :)

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a string contains digits only, or how to check if a string contains a number? If the latter, would TryParse work, or do you need to check for some specific format? If the latter, there's regex.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your interest, the problem is to check if a string contains only digits i.e. "123142543764"  is ok and "132435_1234" is not ok. I think @Reed got the point perfectly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few different options for approaching this.

Given that `System.String` is a sequence of characters, which you're currently using to turn into a list, you can skip the list conversions and just use [`Seq.forall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.forall%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) to directly test:

```
let strContainsOnlyNumber (s:string) = s |> Seq.forall Char.IsDigit
```

If you want to see if it's a valid number, you can parse it into a number directly:

```
let strContainsOnlyNumber (s:string) = System.Int32.TryParse s |> fst
```

Note that this will also return true for things like `"-342"` (which contains `-`, but is a valid number).

Another approach would be to use a regular expression:

```
let numberCheck = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9]+$")    
let strContainsOnlyNumbers (s:string) = numberCheck.IsMatch s
```

This will also handle numeric characters, but could be adapted to include other symbols in numbers if needed.

If the goal is to later use the string as a number, my suggestion would be to just do a conversion, and store in an option:

```
let tryToInt s = 
    match System.Int32.TryParse s with
    | true, v -> Some v
    | false, _ -> None
```

This will allow you to check to see if the value was a number (via [`Option.isSome`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/option.issome%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D)), pattern match to use the results, and more.

Note that conversions to floating point numbers is nearly identical - just change the `Int32.TryParse` to a `Double.TryParse` if you want to handle `float` values.